# Synapse Notebook reference - how to use %run

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to use the Azure Synapse notebook reference described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks?tabs=preview#notebook-reference

Here is my setup, notebook_1 and notebook_2 are both under root folder of Synapse notebooks.

I have a notebook_1 published in workspace and then trying to call it in notebook_2 using

```
%run 'notebook_1'
```

Got an error syaing:

MagicUsageError: Cannot read notebook 'notebook_1'. The possible reason is that the notebook doesn't exist.

Could anyone give an advice on the proper way of doing that? Many thanks.

Comment: Has notebook_1 been published? If not, it's possible it can't find the reference.

Comment: Both notebook_1 and notebook_2 have been published.

Comment: turns out just %run notebook_1 works

Comment: Just confirming, the quote marks are improper?

Comment: Yes, works after removing the quote

Answer (score 2):

> Try to remove the single quote marks in the notebook to resolve the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that the notebook you're trying to call has been published.
More info on calling a notebook can be found here: [Run another synapse notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/Azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-notebook-activity?tabs=classical#run-another-synapse-notebook) (included below)

> You can reference other notebooks in a Synapse notebook activity via calling %run magic or mssparkutils notebook utilities. Both support nesting function calls. The key differences of these two methods that you should consider based on your scenario are:

> %run magic copies all cells from the referenced notebook to the %run cell and shares the variable context. When notebook1 references notebook2 via %run notebook2 and notebook2 calls a mssparkutils.notebook.exit function, the cell execution in notebook1 will be stopped. We recommend you use %run magic when you want to "include" a notebook file.

> mssparkutils notebook utilities calls the referenced notebook as a method or a function. The variable context isn't shared. When notebook1 references notebook2 via mssparkutils.notebook.run("notebook2") and notebook2 calls a mssparkutils.notebook.exit function, the cell execution in notebook1 will continue. We recommend you use mssparkutils notebook utilities when you want to "import" a notebook.

Comment: What does "nesting function calls" mean in the sentence "Both support nesting function calls."?