# One spark session for all notebook in Synapse

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I don't find any solution fot start one apache spark session for all notebooks in one pipeline, any ideas ?

Comment: if you just want to run another jupyter notebook within a jupyter notebook, you could use `%run` magic. [ref](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/jupyter-notebooks/running-jupy-notebooks.html#running-a-jupyter-notebook-from-another-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: i use synapse notebook

Comment: @Dev, its also valid for synapse notebook. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760592/synapse-notebook-reference-how-to-use-run

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to use 1 Spark session for multiple Synapse notebooks/users.

Synapse provides purpose-built engines for specific use cases. Spark for Synapse is designed as a job service, not a cluster model.

Use %run.

You can use %run  magic command to reference another notebook within current notebook's context. All the variables defined in the reference notebook are available in the current notebook. %run magic command supports nested calls but not support recursive calls. You receive an exception if the statement depth is larger than five.

Comment: No can use run as in nestjng. Variables shared.

Comment: Its in the manual

Answer (score 0):

The Spark pools cannot be used in multiple Notebook but spark session can be used in multiple Notebook
create spark session in Notebook1
and use in all notebook using

```css
%run NotebookName
```

then run remaining codes
note:-it can done in azure synapse notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `runMultiple()` method available in the "Microsoft Spark Utilities" library.

In [Reference run multiple notebooks in parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python#reference-run-multiple-notebooks-in-parallel) it's mentioned that:

> The method `mssparkutils.notebook.runMultiple()` allows you to run multiple notebooks in parallel or with a predefined topological structure.

and,

> With `mssparkutils.notebook.runMultiple()`, you can:
>
> - Execute multiple notebooks simultaneously, without waiting for each one to finish.
> - Specify the dependencies and order of execution for your notebooks, using a simple JSON format.
> - Get the exit value of each executive activity and use them in downstream tasks.

Here's a simple example of running a list of notebooks in parallel using this method:

```
mssparkutils.notebook.runMultiple(["NotebookSimple", "NotebookSimple2"])
```

The execution result from the root notebook is as follows:

[image: Screenshot of reference a list of notebooks.]